# Visual Studio 13 + Chutzpah - Where do I find chutzpah.console.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, jasmine, chutzpah

We want to use chutzpah (VS Extension) to run our Jasmine-tests with MSBuild (In a TFS-build). So I'm trying to locate chutzpah.console.exe (so that we can manually call it) somewhere on the local computer, but I cannot find it. Does anyone know where it is usually located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you **also have to install** the chutzpah-nuget package

```
PM> Install-Package Chutzpah
```

(even though the VS Extension seems to run anyway), then you will find the chutzpah.console.exe under: *Chutzpah.3.2.4\tools*.

Comment: Yes the Nuget package for Chutzpah installs the standalone tools which are not included in the VS Extension. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah